# file or directory not found for "UIConstants.js"

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

In Hamattan Application Project in Qt Creator. when I'm trying to import:

```
import "UIConstants.js" as UIConstants
```

I always get file or directory not found error after building. It tried to copy the file into my project, the same error pops out.

What could have gone wrong? Please Help, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's either of these two:

1. forgot to add it in res.qrc
2. it was located at a different directory(but is included in the project)